# Bind failed : Bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm new to socket programming and here I'm trying to set up a simple server socket and listen on it. Here's my code.

```
 int server_socket, client_socket, sent;
    size_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char msg[] = "Hello to the world of socket programming";
    server_socket == socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(server_socket == -1){
        perror("Socket creation failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //define server
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(10000);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&server.sin_zero, '\0', 8);


    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if((bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, len)) == -1){
        perror("Bind failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(listen(server_socket, 5) == -1){
        perror("Listen failed: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(true){

        if((client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&len)) == -1){

            perror("Accept failed: ");
            exit(-1);
        }

        sent = send(client_socket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

        printf("Sent %d byte to client: %s\n", sent, inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

        close(client_socket);

    }
```

I keep getting

```
Bind Failed : Bad file descriptor
```

However my file descriptor is exactly as per beej guide. Any help?

Comment: this line: `memset(&server.sin_zero, '\0', 8);` is very 'iffy'.  much better to (before setting any fields in 'server'  `memset(&server, '\0', sizeof( server) ); and remove the current call to memset()

Comment: Did you #include all the necessary header files?  the posted code is missing that info.  needs: stdio.h  stdlib.h sys/types.h sys/socket.h netinet/in.h arpa/inet.h  and perhaps a few others.  Did you compile the code with all the warnings enabled?  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
server_socket == socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

You're not assigning anything to `server_socket`.  You're comparing it against the return value of `socket`.  You need to do this:

```
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Since you're listening on a TCP socket, you'll also want to do this:

```
int option=1;
setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&option,sizeof(option));
```

This will prevent the app from experiencing "Address already in use" errors if it is killed and restarted within a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks that helped, but now I'm getting   Bind failed: : Address already in use

Comment: In my app, I'd need the user to run the program explicitly as a client or server using a specific port number, like app c 2345 or app s 2341. Do I still need to use setsockopt?

Comment: It's only needed for the server side.  You would set `SO_REUSEADDR` before calling `listen`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's caused by a typo :

```
server_socket == socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

should be :

```
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```